# Example of a group $G$ with exactly $n$ subgroups (including the trivial one and $G$ itself).

Tags: combinatorics, group-theory, examples-counterexamples

I'm reading *"Contemporary Abstract Algebra,"* by Gallian.

This is Exercise 4.39.

> Give an example of a group that has exactly $6$ subgroups (including the trivial one and the group itself). Generalise to exactly $n$ subgroups for any positive integer $n$.

*My Attempt:*

I *suspect* that $\Bbb Z_{p^3q}$ has six subgroups for distinct primes $p$ and $q$. Why? Because I can sort of visualise its subgroup Hasse diagram as two parallelograms of the same size, sharing an edge of the same size, with exactly six vertices/nodes on the diagram corresponding to the subgroups.

The above is vague. I'm not interested in computing the subgroups (yet) as I doubt doing so would be edifying.

So I can't say for sure whether my candidate group works.

---

The solutions in the book are as follows (and I quote):

> "For $6$, use $\Bbb Z_{2^5}$. For $n$, use $\Bbb Z_{2^{n-1}}$."

---

### My main problem:

> How does one go about answering Exercise 4.39 using the tools available in the book so far, without doing too many calculations?

Please help.

Comment: The only result you need here is that a cyclic group of order $n$ has a unique subgroup of each order $m$ dividing $n$, which is elementary.

Comment: Ah, of course! Thank you, @DerekHolt :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**Hint**: If $G $ is a cyclic group of order $n$, then for each positive integer $m$ dividing  $n$ there is a unique subgroup of  $G$ of order $m $. How many divisors are there for  $2^{n-1}$?